# Batch file: Read file, set variable, echo variable

Tags: file, variables, batch-file

So I am going crazy. I'm fairly good with most languages but batch programming makes me crazy.

All i want to do is:

1. Create a loop that reads file (line by line)
2. Each loop read each line into an array
3. Each loop read each array value into a separate variable
4. Use that variable, let's say echo that variable

Anyone?

Comment: What's wrong with using any of the [multiple duplicate questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+read+file+array)?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off

rem Next command is required to easily manage array elements
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Create a loop that reads file (line by line)
set numLines=0
for /F "delims=" %%a in (file.txt) do (
   rem Each loop read each line into an array
   set /A numLines+=1
   set "line[!numLines!]=%%a"
)

rem Use that variable, let's say echo that variable
for /L %%i in (1,1,%numLines%) do echo !line[%%i]!
```

I suggest you to read: [Arrays, linked lists and other data structures in cmd.exe (batch) script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)